# Add fixed editor to copied google sheet

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a Google Sheet that I share with a lot of people, and I often need to provide help to the people to make small adjustments to the sheet to make it fit better for their purpose. So far, I have managed this by getting people to manually make me an editor of the file, but I believe I should be able to automate this using apps script. Preferably I would have this trigger automatically upon copying the file.

What I am hoping to achieve is that people make a copy of the file, and once they make a copy the file is automatically shared with me (editor rights), if it cannot be done fully automatically I would be OK with a workaround where the user still be prompted to give access, simply by a "OK" or "agree" kind of button.

Thanks in advance for your help

I found this potential solution on youtube:

```
function shareFile() {
 const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
 const fileId = sheet.getRange(2, 1).getValue();
 const emailAndPermissions = sheet.getRange(2, 2, sheet.getLastRow() - 1, 2).getValues();
 const fileToShare = DriveApp.getFileById(fileId);

 emailAndPermissions.forEach(function(emailAndPermission) {
    if(emailAndPermission[1] === "Viewer") {
       fileToShare.addViewer(emailAndPermission[0]);
    }
    else if (emailAndPermission[1] === "Commenter") {
       fileToShare.addCommenter(emailAndPermission[0]);
    }
    else if (emailAndPermission[1] === "Editor") {
       fileToShare.addEditor(emailAndPermission[0]);
    }
    else {
       SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert("Permission must be 'Viewer', 'Commenter', or 'Editor'. Please check your input.")
    }
  });
}
```

I reworked this to my use-case, which would just require the Editor section and a fixed email address (so would prefer to skip creating a sheet and look the email address up in the range).

```
function shareFile() {
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet;
  const fileId = "<target email address>";
  const fileToShare = DriveApp.getFileById(fileId);

  fileToShare.addEditor(fileId);
}
```

However, when I try to run this I am getting this error code:

Exception: Unexpected error while getting the method or property getFileById on object DriveApp.
shareFile   @ Code.gs:4

Could anyone help me in finding my mistake?